# Spring Session JDBC Expiration Cron in a multi Container environement

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We store SpringBoot 2.x sessions in MySQL via standard Spring JDBC session storage

We have 10 Spring containers running (in K8S) simultaneously  and we encounter some locking problem on the sessions table, cause all the 10 containers run a DELETE query (DELETE FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE EXPIRY_TIME <...) to purge expired session at the same time

We have found the spring.session.jdbc.cleanup-cron to change the delete scheduling but no option to make it run on only one of the running containers

Thanks

We want to purge expired sessions in a performant way